# How to only route office traffic over the VPN while having default route for other traffic?

Tags: macos, vpn, network

I have a VPN to my office and would like to route only office traffic over the VPN while maintaining my default route for other traffic.

I have attempted the following:

```
sudo route delete default
sudo route add default 192.168.1.254
sudo route add 172.0.0.0/8 172.26.7.79
```

Routing table after change:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.254      UGScI           1        0     en1
default            192.168.1.254      UGScI           4        0     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              3      898     lo0
162.119.232.200    192.168.1.254      UGHS            3       78     en0
169.254            link#7             UCS             1        0     en0
172.0/8            172.26.7.79        UGSc            3        0   utun0
172.26.7.79        172.26.7.79        UH             34       95   utun0
192.168.1          link#7             UCS             9        0     en0
192.168.1          link#4             UCSI            3        0     en1
192.168.1.202      127.0.0.1          UHS             0       48     lo0
192.168.1.203      127.0.0.1          UHS             0        2     lo0
192.168.15         link#10            UC              3        0  vmnet8
192.168.99         link#9             UC              2        0  vmnet1
```

When this happens, I can get to 172.0.0.0/8 but I can't get anywhere else.

If I add a default route back such as:

```
sudo route default 172.26.7.79
```

Then everything starts working again.

Starting Routing Table:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            172.26.7.79        UGSc            2        0   utun0
default            192.168.1.254      UGScI           0        0     en1
default            192.168.1.254      UGScI           3        0     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              3      898     lo0
162.119.232.200    192.168.1.254      UGHS            3       94     en0
169.254            link#7             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.1          link#7             UCS             9        0     en0
192.168.1          link#4             UCSI            5        0     en1
192.168.1.202      127.0.0.1          UHS             0       48     lo0
192.168.1.203      127.0.0.1          UHS             0        2     lo0
192.168.15         link#10            UC              3        0  vmnet8
192.168.15.132     0:c:29:14:38:20    UHLWIi          0      152  vmnet8   1136
192.168.99         link#9             UC              2        0  vmnet1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to edit and specify what your VPN setup is.

Answer (score 2):

Use the -ifscope switch to remove the existing default gateways with the UGScI flags:

`sudo route delete default` delete global gateway (presumably assigned by VPN)

`sudo route delete default -ifscope en0` delete en0 dedicated gateway

`sudo route delete default -ifscope en1` delete en1 dedicated gateway

`sudo route add default 192.168.1.254` create new (local) default gateway

`sudo route add 172.0.0.0/8 172.26.7.79` create office traffic route

Answer (score 1):

This is how you route specific traffic over an interface `sudo route add google.com en1` (en1 is the interface).

In order to find the interface use `ifconfig`command, run the command before and after connecting VPN and determine on which interface the VPN is running.

[A similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/4904/how-to-selectively-route-network-traffic-through-vpn-on-mac-os-x-leopard) has a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a checkbox in network preferences under your VPN entry labelled

```
"send all traffic over vpn connection"
```

that you just need to uncheck, then restart your vpn connection.

Comment: This checkbox is not always available for Cisco IPSec networking.

Comment: yes @algal - most companies insist that split tunneling be disabled by policy and the vendors allow that restriction to be enforced technically.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever supports your VPN need to enable split tunneling. As a workaround, you could do all your VPN work within a VM, while the host system can still access your own network.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that the user has the ability to install the (potentially proprietary and access-restricted) VPN client within a VM?